# KeyDown event in applescript objective-c Xcode

Tags: xcode, applescript, textfield, keydown

I would like to be able to access the KeyDown event in a textfield. In the code below I wrote a normal method called TextfieldKeyDown, and linking it to the textfield from the delegate list, when enter is pressed the method code is started. How can I execute the method when I press, for example, the letter D or the letter F?

```
on TextfieldKeyDown_(sender)
    log "Enter Pressed"
end TextfieldKeyDown_
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Your handler is just a regular action method, which is usually called when editing in the textField is finished.  For additional control, you can add a **NSControlTextEditingDelegate** method to watch for changes to the textField.

In the **Interface Editor**, connect your textField’s delegate to the class/file you are going to use (the AppDelegate, for example), then add the `controlTextDidChange:` method to it:

```
on controlTextDidChange_(aNotification) -- example to show character at insertion point
  set theTextField to aNotification's object() -- the control being changed
  set {theText, theEditor} to {stringValue(), currentEditor()} of theTextField
  set insertPoint to (location of first item of (theEditor's selectedRanges() as list)) as integer
  if (theText as text is not "") and (insertPoint is not 0) then
    set theCharacter to text insertPoint of (theText as text) -- the added character
  else
    set theCharacter to "(none)"
  end if
  log "character at insertion point: " & theCharacter — show it
end
```

Comment: Unfortunately doesn't work. This is the error: 2019-04-05 23:02:44.448360+0200 KeyDown App[2842:130500] -[NSTextField object]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x100708520

Comment: I copied my example method directly from a working project - the `NSTextField object` error looks like you made some changes?

Comment: Even removing all the code in the method and leaving only for example -> (log "Pressed") does not work.

Comment: Is the `delegate` outlet of the textField connected to the delegate object containing the handler?  If all you are using is `AppDelegate.applescript`, you can also use NSTextField's delegate method somewhere like `applicationWillFinishLaunching`, for example `set myTextField's delegate to me` (or whatever the textField's name is).